# Chemical functional groups: in chemmacros package, selectively interpret dash or similar as a bond, not as a charge

Tags: chemistry, chemmacros

I am using the `ch` command in the [`chemmacros`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros?lang=en) package to typeset chemical formulas. I would like to typeset chemical *functional groups*. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\ch{Cl-Cl}\\
\ch{Cl-}\\
\ch{-Cl}\\
\noindent%
How do I obtain Cl-- using \verb=\ch=?

\end{document}
```

... which gives this output:

[image: functional group]

How can I get `ch` to interpret `Cl-` or similar as the *functional group* Cl, rather than the ion Cl? The dash `-` here is a bond, not a charge? If possible, I would like this to be done selectively (i.e., when I specify), not every time.

Comment: You could use `\ch{Cl\bond{sb}}`, see the manual of the `chemformula` package (which is the one defining `\ch`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enclose the `-` in a set of `{}` to "hide" it from `chemmacros`/`chemformula`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}
\ch{Cl-Cl}

\ch{Cl{-}}

\end{document}
```